# sqlcommand.executereader returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-core

After calling this procedure :

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SLTxtMainGetAll]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT [Id]
      ,[IsAnnouncement]
      ,[Text]
      ,[TextLanguage] 
    FROM SLTxtMain;
END
```

C# code calling this procedure is:

```
private SqlDataReader _reader;

_command = _connection.CreateCommand();
_command.Transaction = _transaction;
_command.CommandTimeout = 300;
_command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
_command.CommandText = "SLTxtMainGetAll";

_reader = _command.ExecuteReader(); // This returns null
```

What's happening? Where might be a problem?

Comment: It shouldn't return null.  Try to create a simple repro, and post that if you can.

Comment: You shouldn't cache connection, command and reader objects anyway. Create when you need, dispose with `using` as soon as you are fininshed

Comment: yo problem was Connection OPEN CLOSE  and connection string